# LWJGL: Can't render more than one shape in opengl

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

just doing some tinkering with lwjgl and making some 2d shapes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong but I'm not able to show more than the first green square on screen. Here is the code for my window loop function:

```
private void loop() {
// This line is critical for LWJGL's interoperation with GLFW's
// OpenGL context, or any context that is managed externally.
// LWJGL detects the context that is current in the current thread,
// creates the GLCapabilities instance and makes the OpenGL
// bindings available for use.
GL.createCapabilities();
GLFWVidMode vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
glOrtho(0, vidmode.width(),0, vidmode.height(),-1,1);

// Set the clear color
glClearColor(.0f, 0.6f, 0.6f, 0.0f);


// Run the rendering loop until the user has attempted to close
// the window or has pressed the ESCAPE key.
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window) && !dataH.isGameOver()) {


    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // clear the framebuffer

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    {
        glColor3f(0.1f, 1.0f, 0.1f);  // Green
        glVertex2d(xMapCentre - 100,yMapCentre - 100);
        glVertex2d(xMapCentre - 100,yMapCentre + 100);
        glVertex2d(xMapCentre + 100,yMapCentre + 100);
        glVertex2d(xMapCentre + 100,yMapCentre - 100);

        glColor3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f); // Dark Gray
        glVertex2f(-0.9f, -0.7f);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // White
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.7f);
        glColor3f(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f); // Dark Gray
        glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.3f);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // White
        glVertex2f(-0.9f, -0.3f);
    }
    glEnd();



    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);          // Each set of 3 vertices form a triangle
    {
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue
    glVertex2f(0.1f, -0.6f);
    glVertex2f(0.7f, -0.6f);
    glVertex2f(0.4f, -0.1f);

    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
    glVertex2f(0.3f, -0.4f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green
    glVertex2f(0.9f, -0.4f);
    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Blue
    glVertex2f(0.6f, -0.9f);
    }
    glEnd();


    glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers
    // Poll for window events. The key callback above will only be
    // invoked during this call.
    glfwPollEvents();
}
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, and let me know if I'm being too vague. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when rendering 2D structures in 3D space, you should disable the back-face culling `glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE)`. Otherwise you can only see them from one side. In your shaders you have to be aware of the normal direction.

In the 2D only case, check for your winding order of the triangles if you want to have back or front face culling, set `glFontFace(GL_CCW)` or `glFrontFace(GL_CW)` for counter-clockwise and clockwise winding order respectively. (I cant confirm if the winding order makes a difference in 2D when using `glVertex2f`)

Also try to diable the depth test and depth write `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` and `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE)`.